# How can one create a product through gumroad API

Tags: payment-processing, gumroad

I have been searching for a while and read the API documentation for gumroad, but i'm not able to find  any API endpoint which could allow me to create a product in gumroad using there API.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just been wondering the same thing actually. Gumroad can post info to a Webhook once a purchase is made (Called a Ping). You'd need to have an API endpoint of your own ready to accept this info. This API back-end of yours would need to setup whatever products you want to configure after that.